# PHP e Javascript - Enviar e-mail quando label é clicado

Tags: php, javascript, envio-de-email, phpmailer, label

Tenho um formulário na minha página, sendo que parte dele pode ser impresso ao ser clicado em um label de Imprimir:

```
<label id="printEvento" class="textDescricaoSobre font13" style="cursor: pointer">IMPRIMIR EVENTO</label>
```

Em seguida, outro label pode dar pro usuário a opção de enviar essa parte do formulário por e-mail:

```
<label name="enviaEmail" class="textDescricaoSobre font13" style="cursor: pointer">ENVIAR POR E-MAIL</label>
```

Contudo, não estou conseguindo criar o código (seja em PHP ou Javascript ou os dois juntos) que faça o envio desse e-mail e avise que o envio aconteceu através de um alerta. Na verdade, o alerta é possível, mas apenas em Javascript.

Como eu posso fazer? Utilizo a biblioteca PHPMailer junto?

Comment: Você está usando um elemento do HTML que nativamente não tem eventos associados, logo, você necessariamente deverá usar javascript para manipular o evento de click nessas labels

Comment: Para o seu código você pretende que o envio dos dados seja com o ou sem refresh da página?

Comment: @AdrianoLuz Preferia sem o refresh. Mas pode ser com também, se não tiver jeito.

Comment: Sem refresh. Nesse caso você vai precisar utilizar ajax, por acaso está usando jquery?

Comment: @AdrianoLuz Por enquanto não. Mas já utilizei em outros sites. Como eu posso fazer?

Comment: Por que ao invés de usar `<label>` você não utilizar `<form>`? Assim você poderá utilizar botões para enviar os dados sem a necessidade de atrelar scripts

Comment: @AdrianoLuz OK, como é um formulário em duas partes, eu dividi cada uma em um form e troquei o label por um input. Vou continuar aqui, obrigado.